# Concurrency Exception ASP MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a system where users gets a token from the database; the row is updated after it has been accessed. I have handled concurrency such that when there is DbUpdateConcurrencyException the code is re-run to select a row which isn't updated yet. However it returns

> InnerException    {"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

for rows that are not yet updated.

My model is below:

```
  public int ID { get; set; }
    public int serial { get; set; }
    public int pin { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

And this is the controller:

```
 public string Post()
    {
        bool tryAgain = true;
        while (tryAgain)
        {
            var myDatatToUpdate = (db.loginKeys.FirstOrDefault(b => b.status == null));
            try
            {
                myDatatToUpdate.status = "done";
                db.SaveChanges();
                tryAgain = false;
                return (myDatatToUpdate.ID.ToString());
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {

            }


        }
        return "done";

    }
```

Comment: Hi, where, and how do you define `db`?

Comment: It is an instance of ApplicationDbContext. private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

Comment: sorry for being out of context but Dapper ORM works better for multi-user issues :)

Comment: Th thing is: you seem to change these records while you are working on them,. Perhaps from another thread. The question is: what doe you want to do with it? Go ahead? Or is the exception a valid one?